# Code Builder Web IDE - What role third party websites plays?

Tags: ide

While installing code builder managed package in one of sandbox org, we came across a step to provide access to third-party website and endpoints. After seeing this step, we canceled the installation thinking that providing access will compromise the security of our org. I searched everywhere to understand what are those sites and the what is the purpose and never found any details on it. Can someone explains why we need to provide access and what if we don't?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Code Builder Web IDE is a customized VS Code. You can see the vanilla version [here](https://vscode.dev/). The customizations make it suitable to develop on the Salesforce Platform. If you navigate to [code.com](https://code.com/), you'll see it redirects to [salesforce.com](https://salesforce.com/). In other words, it's just one of the many domains that salesforce.com has bought up for their services (along with, for example, [force.com](https://force.com/)).

It is absolutely 100% safe to accept the third-party access connections. If you do not accept these connections, the IDE will still run, but you will be unable to retrieve or deploy metadata, and most of the Salesforce-related functionality will be effectively disabled.